# Convergence of time derivative in time-dependent Sobolev space

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, banach-spaces, sobolev-spaces

Suppose $\{u_{n}\}_{n}$ is a sequence of smooth functions in space and time such that $u_{n} \to u$ in $L^{\infty}(0,T; L^{\infty}(\Omega))$, where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}$ is open, bounded.

**Question:** Can we say anything about the regularity of $\partial_{t}u$? Does it exist at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course not. There is no need to consider such fancy spaces. Take $u_n(t, x)=f_n(t)$. Your assumption implies that $f_n\to f$ uniformly, where $f=f(t)$. You cannot conclude anything on $f'$, as you already know.

Comment: Of course. Thank you for the reality check. I was getting all muddled up in interpolation inequalities as part of trying to solve a bigger problem and I seem to have overlooked the basics.

Comment: No problem, glad it helped. If you want to say something on $\partial_t$ your space must be $W^{1,p}(0, T; X)$, where $X$ is some Banach space, and $p\in [1, \infty]$.